# windows 10, Admin account has no access

Tags: windows-10

When I try to open Edge or even the calculator, I get a message "This app can"t be opened using the built in administrator account" 
I have read numerous posts that this is for security, blah blah, a calculator or a built in web browser is a security risk? 
How do I access the policy management editor in windows 10? it is different than 7 or 8. search brings up nothing, is it called something else?

Comment: Try `Win`+`R` and type `gpedit.msc` for the group policy editor, or `secpol.msc` for the local security policy editor.

Answer (score 0):

This is disabled for security as you've stated (more to protect you from running third party store apps as the main built in administrator account), but if you do want to override this:

### If you have Windows 10 Home

Windows 10 Home doesn't have the local security policy editor. I can't test this, but apparently you can try these steps:

Open `regedit`

Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`

Create a `DWORD` value if it doesn’t already exist called `FilterAdministratorToken`

Set the value to 1

Next, navigate to here:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\UIPI\`

Change the `Default` string key to `1`

Also, in addition to the above, make sure your User Account Control Setting is set to the third level from the bottom.  To get to `UAC`, go to your Windows 10 search and type uac.  It should come up as `Change User Account Control Settings`.

Finally, restart Windows and then you will be able to enjoy Edge under your Built-in Administrator account.

### If you have Windows 10 Pro/Enterprise

- Navigate to your local security policy on your Windows 10 workstation – You can do this by typing `secpol.msc` at a search/run/command prompt.
- Under `Local Policies/Security Options` navigate to `User Account Control Admin Approval Mode for the Built-in Administrator account`
- Set the policy to `Enabled`

[image]

Source: [here](http://www.virtualizationhowto.com/2015/07/windows-10-edge-opened-builtin-administrator-account/)